# Why the button change is frame color when i click on it?

Tags: css

I create a button, but have a problem.
When i click the button the frame color change and i don't understand why.
I upload image before and after clicked.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Button css:

```
.aproveBtn
  background: $add-button
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $add-button, $add-button)
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, $add-button, $add-button)
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, $add-button, $add-button)
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, $add-button, $add-button)
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, $add-button, $add-button)
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px
  -moz-border-radius: 4px
  border-radius: 4px
  font-family: Arial
  color: #ffffff
  @include font-size(20)
  padding: 0px 35px 2px 36px
  text-decoration: none
```

Thanks

Comment: it is because a button has its frame color inversed when clicked. You can compare it with a normal button without any css and that same button but clicked

Answer (score 0):

If it's "button" tag, just read about outline, and you can set it as none: `outline: none;`
And also read about focus and active pseudo classes in CSS. Hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: I had outline:none but its still same problem